# hard drive gets seen too late by the kernel after upgrading to debian bullseye

Tags: usb, hard-drive, mount, fstab

i just swapped out my old rpi sd card with raspbian stretch for one with raspian bullseye because stretch didnt gave me kernel 5.x and it felt outdated. everything worked so far except that my usb hard drive doesn't mount because it gets seen too late by the kernel. any ideas?

raspberry pi 3 b+ armv7l linux 5.10.63-v7+ raspbian (debian) bullseye

`sudo dmesg`:

```
...
[    6.531430] systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b3f635b5\x2dbc12\x2d4196\x2db384\x2dfff32368c9e4.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b3f635b5\x2dbc12\x2d4196\x2db384\x2dfff32368c9e4.device/start timed out.
[    6.542488] systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/b3f635b5-bc12-4196-b384-fff32368c9e4.
[    6.555582] systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/b3f635b5-bc12-4196-b384-fff32368c9e4.
[    6.568154] systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /srv/nfs.
[    6.577123] systemd[1]: srv-nfs.mount: Job srv-nfs.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
[    6.585016] systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b3f635b5\x2dbc12\x2d4196\x2db384\x2dfff32368c9e4.service: Job systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b3f635b5\x2dbc12\x2d4196\x2db384\x2dfff32368c9e4.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
[    6.597635] systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b3f635b5\x2dbc12\x2d4196\x2db384\x2dfff32368c9e4.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b3f635b5\x2dbc12\x2d4196\x2db384\x2dfff32368c9e4.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
...

...
[   10.288933] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ST950042 3AS              0041 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[   10.290492] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[   10.290544] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[   10.291134] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[   10.291158] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[   10.291908] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[   10.291929] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   10.306171] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[   10.306347] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[   10.313173] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4345/6 wl0: Nov  1 2021 00:37:25 version 7.45.241 (1a2f2fa CY) FWID 01-703fd60
[   10.421495]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 sdb4
[   10.426561] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
...
```

fstab line:

```
UUID=b3f635b5-bc12-4196-b384-fff32368c9e4   /srv/nfs    ext4    nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=100ms       0 2
```

Comment: Could be an *adjustment* is needed in the `systemd` sequence... you might look at `systemd-analyze` to gain insight. Can you mount the drive manually after your system has fully booted using `mount -a`? If not, can it be mounted manually?

Comment: both `mount -a` and `mount /dev/sdb1` work

Comment: `$ systemd-analyze`
`Startup finished in 4.158s (kernel) + 16.120s (userspace) = 20.278s`
`graphical.target reached after 15.615s in userspace`

Comment: Based on that, I'll guess that the cure for your issue is to have `systemd` postpone the `mount` operation on this drive. How to do that? I'm not well-versed in `systemd`, and our resident `systemd GURU` @ingo is on sabbatical. All I can suggest is this: If you don't get a useful answer here, post a similar question on the Super User -or- Unix & Linux SE sites.

Comment: P.S. to ensure I see your comments, preface your comment with my handle: **@seamus**.

Comment: what you mean by upgrade? `sudo apt upgrade` didnt give me updates anymore so i flash a new os from raspberrypi.org on an SD and put it in my pi so yeah fresh install

Comment: I find it odd that this is `sg1` and `sdb` ... is there an `sg0` / `sda`?

Comment: @Bravo `/dev/sda` is my old SD in an adapter

Comment: @Milliways what do you mean by misinformation

Comment: Can you please confirm whether or not this *automount* (`/etc/fstab`) entry refers to a **network drive**, or to a USB-connected drive?? I ask because your the mount point you're using is `/srv/nfs` - which is a bit *odd* to my eyes.

Comment: its a usb hard drive as i said in my question

Comment: is it even possible to get a network drive on `/dev/sd{a..z}`?

Answer (score 1):

Increase the value you pass with the parameter **x-systemd.device-timeout** which is currently set to 100ms.
Maybe try 250ms

Comment: will that work? the device is seen 4 seconds later than systemd tries to mount its filesystem

Comment: it complains about timing out, so your timeout option is probably it. How much it must be increased depends on your drive. I'd just remove the timeout option and leave only the nofail option. But that could delay the entire boot process a bit depending on the drive.

Answer (score 1):

`x-systemd.device-timeout=100ms` is ridiculously small for a mechanical drive, which can easily take 5-10 seconds to spin-up. The fact that it worked in Stretch is just a coincidence. Since the partition data which defines the existence of e.g. `/dev/sda1` resides on the drive, such device files will not be created until the disk is fully operational.

I recommend you simply remove this option from your `fstab`, unless you actually want to avoid mounting slower drives. If you just want to avoid delaying the boot process then `nofail` alone is sufficient, as if effectively says `local-fs.target` should not wait for the mount process to complete.